# How do i paginate objects grouping by their date in each page?

Tags: django, django-pagination

Trying to paginate a list of objects by their date.

For example:

```
page 1 -> objects date is smaller than today
page 2 -> objects date is equals to today
page 3 -> objects date is equals to tomorrow
```

and so on.
Each page can have different number of elements.

Comment: I am guessing you wan to do this in your template

Comment: actually i want to create infinite scroll and every time i need to fetch the next date

Answer (score 0):

From django documentation.

```
cities = [
    {'name': 'Mumbai', 'population': '19,000,000', 'country': 'India'},
    {'name': 'Calcutta', 'population': '15,000,000', 'country': 'India'},
    {'name': 'New York', 'population': '20,000,000', 'country': 'USA'},
    {'name': 'Chicago', 'population': '7,000,000', 'country': 'USA'},
    {'name': 'Tokyo', 'population': '33,000,000', 'country': 'Japan'},
]

{% regroup cities by country as country_list %}

<ul>
{% for country in country_list %}
    <li>{{ country.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for city in country.list %}
          <li>{{ city.name }}: {{ city.population }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This is pretty much what you need.
read more over here [django regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup)

Comment: thanks for the response however i am trying to create infinite scroll and in each fetch i need to fetch the other day. i found that i need to use pagination to create infinite scroll but i guess django pagination doesnt support paginating by grouping in the view